# OpenGL transparent texture (blending)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, opengl

I need to make one of my textures transparent. How can I do it?

All code that handles my texture is:

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureImg);
```

What i have to change/add to make texture fully transparent (full-alpha)?

Comment: Please note that having a transparent texture isn't the same as rendering transparent geometry. Blending is one thing you'll need, z-sorting is probably another.

Comment: @Kos I will explain what i'm doing. I load image and make texture from it. And i need to change texture's alpha channel to 0. In the case so i could change alpha from 0.0 to 1.0 in future with something like brush tool. I use multi texturing, so one texture is on the another, so if second texture alpha is set to 0, only first texture will be visible, and when i change it to 1 - second texture will be visible. I don't think i will need z-sorting. But thanks for help.

Comment: Oh, if you don't want to draw transparent geometry and plan to use the alpha channel only for mixing different textures to achieve a final colour on an opaque object, then indeed you need neither blending nor z-sorting. Just sample all the textures in your fragment shader and get the final colour there using any equation you want (like `T1.rgb*T1.a+T2.rgb*(1-T1.a`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code provided simply sets up the texture. You will need to also enable blending using

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

and set up the appropriate [blending function](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm).

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggested solution and give a feedback.